# Password Encryption in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, rest, flask, password-encryption, fernet

On receiving a GET request in Flask, I connect to a backend database and send the response. Currently, the username and password of the database are stored in an ini file. What is the best way to encrypt the username and password?
Also is it good practice to encrypt the username and password for REST calls ? as I need to decrypt every time on receiving a request

Answer (score 1):

You never store plain password in you database. Instead, you want to store **hashes** -- the special sum, which can't be decoded, but will produce the same result on same data.
Therefore, you can just apply this function to plain password and compare it to the one on your database

Take a look at `bcrypt` module:
https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

On your register method:
`pw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash('some_password')`

And then you only store pw_hash in your db

On your login method just extract `pw_hash` from db and compare it:
`bcrypt.check_password_hash(pw_hash, 'password_from_request') # returns True or False`

At the same time, you can store plain username in DB if you want, there's nothing wrong with it

Comment: I guess there is a slight misunderstanding. My  question is about encrypting the passwords which is used to "connect" to the database not stored in the database. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

On your server, you cannot encrypt the username and password to access your database, otherwise you cannot access it.

Usually, you do not put them in a file, but in an environment variable.

Also see the twelve factor app:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-Factor_App_methodology

P.S.: For instance, I use `batou` for deployment (similar to Ansible).

The username and password are both encrypted in a gpg file, so I can check them into version control. But of course, when I deploy the app to production, both values need to be un-encrypted.

https://batou.readthedocs.io/en/stable/